# Type that doesn't allow prototype to be set

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to prevent surprising properties from appearing in my objects by formalizing the prototype. I want my type to always have this be true:

`Object.getPrototypeOf(myObj) === Object.prototype`

And have something like this throw a compile error (just an example, consider anything that would set/modify the prototype of an object):

```
type Pojo = {
  // some magic setting I want to learn
}

const myObj: Pojo = Object.create(Array.prototype); // error!
```

In this case, `Array.prototype` is in the prototype chain of `myObj`, which would break my hypothetical type declaration because Array methods like `indexOf` could be found there.

Comment: That's going to be tough to accomplish without altering the [library declarations for `Object.create()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.7.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L181-L192), since it's declared to return `any`.  Why, specifically, are you worried about this?  You might make some kind of runtime test and have `Pojo` be a [nominal-ish type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html) to prevent anyone from creating a `Pojo` without your runtime code, but that's cumbersome.

Comment: Well, in my example, `myObj.indexOf` evaluates as a function, but typescript is also happy to consider it as the `Pojo` type, which has no such property. This seems surprising. I declared it to have no properties, but now it seems to have one. Can't I do better controlling that?

Comment: `{}` has no *known* properties.  It doesn't mean that it has no properties at all.  TypeScript's object types are open, not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936).  [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7LgLmQGcwpQBzZAXwChRJZEUAhOKZCAD0hABMi0mHMgBGhEAFcAtiOjUaCdCBKi2hVuwC8wgsgBEegDSjCABmoBuBUpUxMhDFm0i2F5AHp3ydAGs4ATxpPZDt0ADoRDk5gEgERCTBkGOQQdESAKmQfVIB3EGRMsCwuGLAaIA)

Comment: Ah, "exact" types are exactly what I'm looking for. If you'll answer I'll accept.